# about Android Context issue

Tags: android, android-context

Issue describe:

firstly,we have 2(or > 2) system level resources (framework-res.apk && xxx-frameworks-res.apk && and so on)

secondly, add the  system level resources

`AssetManager.cpp`

```
| AssetManager::addDefaultAssets()

    | addAssetPath(path, NULL); (add first)

    | addAssetPath(xxxpath, NULL);(add secondly)
```

`

thirdly,use the ManifestExplorer.apk to resolve all installed apks's manifest.xml (include frameworks-res.apk,xxx-frameworks-res.apk).

unfortunately,There are something wrong to resolve "android" and "xxx",
**the same information.**
Different order to add different info.（off course,one of "android" or "xxx"）

**With my analysis:**
The Context issue.

one or more system level resource sharing the only one system Context.

**with my observed result:**

the two resources(framework-res.apk &&xxx-frameworks-res.apk )are not sharing the Context;

The link of the apk's source code [manifest-explorer](https://github.com/iSECPartners/manifest-explorer)

issue picture:

[image: The issue picture]